# strange behaviour in C ? operations priority

Tags: c

I tested the following instruction which gives me a wrong result :

```
float tmp = 26.75 + (data[8] + (((SHORT) data[9]) << 8)) * 0.125 / 64;
```

Then, I tried to separate this instruction in two and it works :

```
SHORT ee =  (data[8] + (((SHORT) data[9]) << 8));                                                                                      
float tmp = 26.75 + ee * 0.125 / 64;
```

I don't understand why this happens.

first_version:

```
float get_TMP () {
    float tmp = 26.75 + (data[8] + (((SHORT) data[9]) << 8)) * (0.125) / 64;
    return tmp;
}
```

last_version :

```
float get_TMP () {
    SHORT ee =  (data[8] + (((SHORT) data[9]) << 8)); 
    float tmp = 26.75 + ee * (0.125) / 64;
    return tmp;
}
```

and data is :

```
unsigned char data[10];
```

Here are the results :
(old) celsius is the result for the "last_version" (ok)
(new) celsius is the result for the "first_version" (error)

[image]

Comment: Please give a complete [mre] including the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: assuming `data` is an array of `int` ... `(data[8] + (((SHORT) data[9]) << 8))` has type `int`; `ee` has type `SHORT` -- their values. after automatic conversion to `int` for `ee`, are not necessarily the same.

Comment: The intermediate steps in your partial expression of interest are done in `int`. In the first snippet the `int` is used directly for the calculation of the final floating-point value, in the second snippet the `int` is converted to `SHORT` before being used for the final floating-point value.

Comment: Note that `char` will have the same range as either `signed char` or `unsigned char`. The choice is implementation-defined.

Comment: Ah ok because we have ```data[8] +```, ```(((SHORT) data[9]) << 8)``` is converted in the type of data (which is char) ? @pmg

Comment: No, all `+`, `-`, `*`, etc are done in `int` or higher. `char a, b, c; c = a + b; /* a + b is int converted back to char for the assignment */`

Comment: @pmg it could also be `unsigned int`, depending on whether `char` is signed or unsigned.

Comment: Very intersting thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should be very careful mixing signed integer types and unsigned integer types. In your example, you could also use `signed char`. However, it is hard to say whether this is what you want.

Assume `data[8] = data[9] = 0xFF`, `char` is unsigned, `SHORT` is `signed short`, which is 16 bit, and `signed int` is 32 bit. Then you compute (the `u` after a constant means that the type is unsigned):

```
0xFFu + (((signed short) 0xFFu) << 8)
=
0xFFu + (0x00FF << 8)
= (integral promotion)
0xFFu + (0x000000FF << 8)
=
0xFFu + 0x0000FF00
= (integral promotion)
0x000000FFu + 0x0000FF00u
=
0x0000FFFFu (an unsigned and positive number)
```

In the first example, you directly convert this number to `float` and get a positive number.

In the second example, you convert this number to `signed short` and obtain 0xFFFF and then back to `signed int` and obtain 0xFFFFFFFF (a signed negative number). Then you convert it to float and obtain a negative number.